# Java Spring - servlets - Uplading file post request does not work for me

Tags: java, spring, file

I have a Java Application using Spring frame work. I am a new learner in this concept. My apologies for making a question which might be very simple.

From the web page user can browse a an excel file and after hitting submit, the excel file should be uploaded to the server and given as an input to a java function in the back end to process it and create a json object.

here is my HTML code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">
<head>

    <meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" name="viewport"></meta>
    <meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type"></meta>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
    <link href="resource/css/main.css" rel="stylesheet"></link>

    <title>My App</title>

</head>

<body>
    <form action="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/uploadServlet" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <input type="text" name="description" />
        <input type="file" name="file" />
        <input type="submit" name="submit"/>
    </form>
    <button id="processData" type="button" class="btn btn-primary">ProcessData</button>
    <br></br>
    <br></br>

    <script src="js/mainJs.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Then I have define my Servlet file as following:

```
/**
 * Servlet implementation class UploadServlet
 */
@WebServlet("/UploadServlet")
@MultipartConfig
@Named //we can use dependacy injection
public class UploadServlet extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Override
    public void init(ServletConfig config) throws ServletException {
        //this is an initialization method that servlet calls when the application starts up 
        super.init(config);
        // this sets up our dependancy injection
        SpringBeanAutowiringSupport.processInjectionBasedOnServletContext(this, config.getServletContext());

    }

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     */
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        String description = request.getParameter("description"); // Retrieves <input type="text" name="description">
        Part filePart = request.getPart("file"); // Retrieves <input type="file" name="file">
        //String fileName = Paths.get(filePart.get).getFileName().toString(); // MSIE fix.
        InputStream fileContent = filePart.getInputStream();
        TestingPost tp = new TestingPost();
        if(request.getParameter("submit") != null) {
            tp.method1(fileContent);//in this method I will process the received excel file
        }
    }



}
```

and here is my java file that plays as controller

```
public class ProcessFile {

    public void method1(InputStream out) {    
        //doing some processing         }
}
```

but when I run the application, browse a file and hit submit I get 404 - 
Do I need to do some thing in my web.xml ?

Comment: In your HTML you have lower case /uploadServlet but your annoatation definition has uppercase /UploadServlet

Comment: @Strelok: that is not the reason, I changed it and still getting 404